# How to export data from the Embold plugin in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, automation, export-to-csv, static-code-analysis

I'm using the Embold plugin in Intellij for static code analysis. I can see a list of issues via the Embold Issues Inspector but how can I see the number of times a specific issues shows up, like God Class, Use of Sysout, Fat Interface, etc. Right now I'm manually counting each but it's a lot. Is there a way I can export this list into a csv file?

Comment: See https://docs.embold.io/installation-and-backup-guide/#analysis-of-output-intellij

Answer (score 0):

There is a export CSV option on the product but currently this option is not there on the plugin.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31130959)